# Is it better to pass linked list object by reference or value?

Tags: c++, parameter-passing

Say you just want to print out the values of the list- do you pass the object by value or reference? Does it matter if you're just printing out the list?

Comment: by reference. it do not watse time to data copy.

Comment: By iterator range. And use std::vector. it's practically always the better choice.

Answer (score 6):

It depends.

Usually the answer is `const&`, because you don't want the overhead of duplicating the data.

But IO is *slow*.  In a sufficiently advanced application, any IO must be done in an async manner.  And async code with references is insanely hard to get right, plus duplicating data is usually much cheaper than IO.  So the answer might be to copy it and do async IO on the copy.

Note that copying most linked lists is more expensive than copying contiguous buffers; so probably you'd copy the linked list into a less dynamic structure (like a buffer or chain of buffers).  And in 99/100 cases you'd want to discard the linked list entirely and use a single buffer or chain of buffers instead, even outside of IO.

Maybe even an immutable vector, as async code loves immutability, and now a "copy" is O(1).

So the easy answer is `const&`, and the complex one is "use a different data structure entirely, where copy means something entirely different".

Answer (score 0):

> do you pass the object by value or reference?

Usually STL containers (including list) can/should be passed by value if you don't need to change the container itself (which is your case here with print). Otherwise if you need to change the container, you should pass by reference).

In C++1x, all STL containers support move semantic (via  move constructors/move assignment operators) which makes the normal C98 pass-by-const-reference unnecessary.

Comment: that is not true. passing by const reference is not even in the slightest unnecessary. if you have a large container and you just wanna do some inspection (for example getting the average of all elements) it is still best to pass by const reference and no copy is made. moving the container into the function would mean you would lose all its content on the callside

Comment: maybe what you mean is: declaring function parameter as pass by value is getting more convenient since we got move semantics. this applies to when you want to make a copy in the callee anyway. temporarys will get constructed into the value parameter and lvalue objects on the call side can cheaply be moved

Comment: +1 for following the advice of Herb Sutter (I believe he was the one to present the new recommendations).